# perform multiple actions within an if

Tags: javascript

How can I perform all the actions in the same if? currently only performs the last

```
if (test==1) {
    document.getElementById("opciones").action='1ExcelArchivos.php'; 
    document.getElementById("opciones").submit();
    document.getElementById("opciones").action='2ExcelArchivos.php'; 
    document.getElementById("opciones").submit();
    document.getElementById("opciones").action='3ExcelArchivos.php'; 
    document.getElementById("opciones").submit();
    document.getElementById("opciones").action='4ExcelArchivos.php'; 
    document.getElementById("opciones").submit();
}
```

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to your question. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending by XMLHttpRequest

```
if (test == 1) {
  var f = document.getElementById("opciones");
  var postData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < f.elements.length; i++) {
    postData.push(f.elements[i].name + "=" + f.elements[i].value);
  }
  var to = ['1ExcelArchivos.php', '2ExcelArchivos.php', '3ExcelArchivos.php', '4ExcelArchivos.php'];
  for (var i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", to[i], true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(postData.join("&"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I want to know where I add test == 1 to be able to perform the action when the user presses 1

Comment: @vizualmarketing It goes around all this -- this just replaces the body of your `if`.

Comment: Could you help me ... I still can't move forward with this. please

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: doing the cycle does not download the files. remains stuck

Comment: if(test==1){document.getElementById("opciones").action='1ExcelArchivos.php'; document.getElementById("opciones").submit();}
if(test==2){document.getElementById("opciones").action='2ExcelArchivos.php'; document.getElementById("opciones").submit();}
if(test==3){document.getElementById("opciones").action='3ExcelArchivos.php'; document.getElementById("opciones").submit();}

Comment: what I need is that each XExcelArchivos.php is downloaded through a for loop

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit what the PHP endpoints are doing, but eventually it is possible to group those files.

Example:

`ExcelArchivos.php`:

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/1ExcelArchivos.php';
require __DIR__ . '/2ExcelArchivos.php';
require __DIR__ . '/3ExcelArchivos.php';
require __DIR__ . '/4ExcelArchivos.php';
```

```js
if (test==1) {
    document.getElementById("opciones").action='ExcelArchivos.php'; 
    document.getElementById("opciones").submit();
}
```

Whether the PHP example is directly fitting or there is a different approach necessary, if at the end of the day you have one endpoint instead of four, you can process this with a single submit.

The browser normally can only process one submit() action at a time as it is related to navigation and there is only one way to navigate. This is also the reason why the last submit() did superseede the earlier ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. integrate the code to have a php page that does the requirements but only considers the first

ExcelArchivos.php:

<? php
require '1ExcelArchivos.php'
require '2ExcelArchivos.php'
?>





 if (test == 1) {document.getElementById ("options"). action = 'ExcelFiles.php'; document.getElementById ("options"). submit ();}

Comment: The example is a pretty simplification. Each of these scripts need to work after each other, if the first one for example calls `exit()` or `die()` or throws an error or exception, it would not work in such a simplified way. review 1-4ExcelArchivos.php and find the parts that is the actual functionality, extract them into 4 new files and then require those in the main file. Also then extend the main file for the request handling if needed. It depends on your code, but that is the part you know best, so if you grasp the example it should be most straight forward as you know it.